# AppleScript choose file dialog box with default location not working

Tags: applescript

So there goes four hours of my life that I will never get back.

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple...

I want to open a file select dialog box and specify the default location.

I actually got this to work using the following...

```
choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} 
default location "/Users/lowken/Dropbox/"
```

This works and does exactly what I want (the file dialog opens up in the Dropbox folder).

However when I try to use a string variable it doesn't work...

```
set strPath to "/Users/lowken/Dropbox/"

choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} 
default location strPath
```

Now the dialog box opens in the root directory of the hard drive :-(

It seems that the default location is being ignored however if the path is not correct Applescript does raise a error.

I've tried casting the value as a string. I even tried to use the POSIX format...

```
"Macintosh HD:Users:lowken:Dropbox"
```

This didn't format didn't work at all.

I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 on a mid 2012 MacBook Pro.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: script worked fine for me.  Maybe a restart to clear things out, or copy and paste script to new editor window.

Comment: It works but it doesn't open to the folder specified by srtPath.

Comment: thats what I'm saying, it does open to the strPath for me.  /Users/username/Dropbox/ and shows my files inside of dropbox.

Comment: Like tron_jones, I have had no trouble running either of your scripts. Have you tried setting the variable to a different path? Perhaps it's an issue with your Dropbox directory.

Comment: At some point, Apple changed how things precompile in AppleScript. I remember running into this problem back in 2012. In my case, there was no workaround. I had to use the string literal. That was not the case with earlier versions of AppleScript.

Answer (score 5):

Both scripts don't work for me. The problem is that the `default location` parameter needs to be of type `alias`. You can fix it by adding `POSIX file` in front of your path (the path does need to exist, otherwise you also get an error message):

```
set strPath to POSIX file "/Users/lowken/Dropbox/"

choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} ¬
    default location strPath
```

Or you could use the "old style" HFS format:

```
set strPath to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:lowken:Dropbox"

choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} ¬
    default location strPath
```